# Linux paste content to default file of Nginx without formation error in cloud-init

Tags: linux, nginx, yaml, echo, cloud-init

i have a problem with my formation in yaml. First of all here is the file:

```
#cloud-config
runcmd:
  - mkdir react
  - cd react
  - type -p curl >/dev/null || sudo apt install curl -y
    curl -fsSL https://cli.github.com/packages/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg | sudo dd of=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg \
    && sudo chmod go+r /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg \
    && echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg] https://cli.github.com/packages stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list > /dev/null \
    && sudo apt update \
    && sudo apt install gh -y
  - curl -o actions-runner-linux-x64-2.301.1.tar.gz -L https://github.com/actions/runner/releases/download/v2.301.1/actions-runner-linux-x64-2.301.1.tar.gz
  - tar xzf ./actions-runner-linux-x64-2.301.1.tar.gz
  - yes "" | ./config.sh --url https://github.com/yuuval/react-deploy --token AVYXWHXNRBPIDXJDPUDK6QTD2LIPE
  - sudo ./svc.sh install
  - sudo ./svc.sh start
  - yes "" | sudo apt install nginx
  - gh auth login --hostname github.com --with-token <<< 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 --git-protocol https
  - gh repo clone yuuval/react-deploy
  - cd react-deploy
  - gh workflow run node.js.yml
  - sleep 70
  - cd /etc/nginx/sites-available
  - sudo rm default
  - echo "server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  # react app & front-end files
  location / {
   root /home/ubuntu/react/_work/react-deploy/react-deploy/build;
   try_files \$uri /index.html;
  }
}" | sudo tee /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
  - sudo service nginx restart
  - sudo chmod +x /home
  - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu
  - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react
  - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react/_work
  - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react/_work/react-deploy
  - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react/_work/react-deploy/react-deploy
  - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react/_work/react-deploy/react-deploy/build
```

The problem is here:

```
echo "server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  # react app & front-end files
  location / {
   root /home/ubuntu/react/_work/react-deploy/react-deploy/build;
   try_files \$uri /index.html;
  }
}" | sudo tee /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

The lines that should go into the default file must have a certain structure. This is the case with the current cloud-init, but it becomes invalid because it does not start at the same line as the "-".  Does anyone have an idea how to get around this?

This is the error of a yaml linter tool:

```
All mapping items must start at the same column at line 25, column 1
Implicit keys need to be on a single line at line 25, column 3
Implicit map keys need to be followed by map values at line 25, column 3
Unexpected flow-map-end token in YAML stream: "}" at line 32, column 1
Unexpected double-quoted-scalar token in YAML stream: "\" | sudo tee /etc/nginx/sites-available/default\n - sudo service nginx restart\n - sudo chmod +x /home\n - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu\n - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react\n - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react/_work\n - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react/_work/react-deploy\n - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react/_work/react-deploy/react-deploy\n - sudo chmod +x /home/ubuntu/react/_work/react-deploy/react-deploy/build" at line 32, column 2
```

line 25 is here: `listen 80 default_server;`

Comment: does switching to `printf "sever....\n....\n.........\n}\n" | sudo tee ...` help? Good luck.

Comment: I dont know what you mean...

Comment: you can replace `echo` with a `printf` string that includes `\n` (line-break) characters. It gives you more control over the output and is less error prone that `echo` output. Seach here for `[bash] printf` and look at some of the examples. If your system has the `info` system built in, try `info printf`. That includes a few small examples that could help. Good luck.